# WordPress, плагин cyr-to-lat в готовом сайте, выдает ошибку 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Сайт существует не так давно, посетителей особо нет, магазин заполнен на 50% , установила плагин cyr-to-lat, естественно, на всех страницах сайта, кроме главной, ошибка 404.

Вопрос: как мне лучше поступить, хотелось бы все же работать с этим плагином, что мне нужно, для того, чтобы Гугл проиндексировал мои новые ссылки?

Спасибо заранее)

Comment: Проблема все таки в том, что старые ссылки не работают? Или в том что никакие страницы не открываются

Comment: Это НЕ естественно. Адрес сайта?

Comment: Зайдите в настройки > ссылки и нажмите сохранить, по идеи должно помочь

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что в Гугле отображались старые ссылки.

Comment: Проблему решили следующим образом: в Search Console  заново просканировали сайт. Установили плагин All 404 Redirect to Homepage, который все неработающие ссылки открывает на главной странице.

Comment: Благодарю за советы)